# How to implement a search function in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am a kind of new to Django. And I am setting up a project that can display quotes based on a specific author or writer. I am having trouble creating the search function to display quotes based on the author's name. How do I create a search view function and display it on the template.

For example, the user searches the author name from author_name in class Author, then it displays a list of quotes by the author

Below is a sample of my models.py file

class Author(models.Model):

```
author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
portrait = models.ImageField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.author_name
```

class Quote(models.Model):

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quote = models.TextField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.quote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given *`author_name`*, you can look up the `Quote`s of that author with:

```
Quote.objects.filter(author__author_name=author_name)
```

You might want to use the [**`__icontains`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains), since this will match `Alexander Pope`, given you search for `pope`, or `alex`:

```
Quote.objects.filter(author__author_name__icontains=author_name)
```